# attribute required for options in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to set attribute `required` for html options in jquery and here are what I tried from reading online and none of them works:

```
$("#transaction_payee_id")[0].setAttribute("required", "true");
$("#transaction_payee_id")[0].setAttribute("required", true);
$("#transaction_payee_id").prop("required", true);
$("#transaction_payee_id").attr("required", true);
```

The first option in html is empty which is required for setup `required`. Here is the html source code. The value for `required` is empty:

```
<select id="transaction_payee_id" name="transaction[payee_id]" class="select required form-control" required="">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">option2</option>
    <option value="2">option2</option>
</select>
```

The command is not complicated. What's missing in the code?

Comment: The problem seems to be that we can only get `required=""`. which has extra `=""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jquery code resetting the `required` works as designed. This problem is caused by `config.validate_browser` on gem `simple_form` which has `false` by default. By resetting it to `true`, the attribute `required` starts working as it should be. Please see the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34235736/rails-attribute-required-for-collection-in-simple-form).

Answer (score 3):

All you need is a form and the required attribute in the form element select.

For example:

```
<form>
  <select required>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="something">someting</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6uLsu25g/

Comment: My question is how to set attribute `required` in execution with jquery code. Not manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the attribute like this :

```
$('select').attr("required","required");
```

This would inject the attribute `required="required"`

http://jsfiddle.net/6uLsu25g/1/

Comment: still same `required = ""` in html source. .prop is the same. Somehow the empty string "" manages to stay. Tried `attr("required", "required")` and it is the same `required=""`

Answer (score 1):

1. As per @Filype's answer `form` is mandatory to make the `required` attribute to work.
2. `<select required>` is similar to `<select required = "">`, `<select required = "required">` and `<select required = true>`(not valid HTML). Please refer [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781355/setting-an-attribute-named-required-and-any-value-with-jquery-doesnt-work) for more information.
3. You can set the `reuqired` attribute dynamically using this `$("#transaction_payee_id").prop("required", "required");` and can remove it by `$("#transaction_payee_id").removeAttr('required');`

**DEMO: [FIDDLE](http://**DEMO:%20[FIDDLE][2]**)**

Hope this helps!