# Rails: Attribute required for collection in simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

We are trying to set `required` in simple_form. The following setup does not work.

```
<%= f.input :payee_id, :label => t('Payee'), required: true, :collection => BankAccountx.payee_class.where(active: true).map {|x| [x.name, x.id]}, :selected => params[:payee_id], include_blank: true %>
```

Also tried `:input_html => {required: true}` and it did not work as well.

What's the right way to set `required` in simple_form?

Comment: Not working. There is no difference with html source code.

Comment: I've tried your settings, it works, could you give more context like gem version, ruby and rails version?

Comment: Interesting. It is Rails 4.2.0, ruby 2.0.0. simple_form 3.1.1. In my test, the * sign shows up for the field. However it saves with empty value.

Comment: your code is mixing the syntax, try :required => true instead of required: true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. If you use this command:

```
rails generate simple_form:install
```

It will create a file at `config/initializer/simple_form.rb`. Find this line

```
config.browser_validations = false
```

And change it to `true`. NOTE: If you just add the gem and not run rails generate, it works by default.

Comment: Yes, it works. We always run the generate when installing simple_form. What's the magic here? Many thanks.

Comment: Actually, simple_form works right when you just add the gem and use it. The generator just used to modify some of its config. Unfortunately, the default of the config file is not what users expect from it. Maybe it changes in later versions?

Comment: `@Hoang Phan` by setting `config.broswer_validations = true`, is this going to change the behaviors of simple_form? We have been using `false` which is the default after running generator.

Comment: It's only affect the behaviors of validations. By default I think simple_form would expect server is the one to manipulate validations, not something like html `required`.

Comment: `Hoang Phan`, does setting `config.validate_browser` to be true bring back the normal behavior of browser? It seems that `required` is the attribute which is not working properly if validate_browser is false.