# .attr() returning attribute name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a html element:

`<input type='text' runat='server' name='RM1' id='RM1' required='5' readonly>`

I need to have the value of the attribute 'required' this I do using jQuery, but when I run

`$('#RM1').attr('required')`

The return value is `"Required"`, though it should be 5.
when I run `$('#RM1').attr('id')` RM1 is returned.

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

note: the code is generated by C# that's `runat` is set to `server`.

Comment: You probably need to use value instead of required. The latter is only true or false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

required is a reserved attribute name for form-validation

Implementations differ but this one is true or false, "Required" evaluates to true and this attribute doesnt need a value at all, if attribute exists = true if not = false,

so:

```
<input required >
<!-- returns the same value (truthy) as -->
<input required="23432abc" >
```

**your solution:** use another attribute name!

Comment: "use another attribute name" - Such as `data-required`. Anything that doesn't start with `data-` might be reserved one day.

Comment: Thats right, but in addition,stick to `.attr()` you can access all of them with  , personaly i realy dont like the inconsistency with `.data()`

Comment: oops, you are right! but still i think `.data()` is unnecessary and  i would advice to stick to `.attr()`

Comment: Why would you stick to `attr`? `attr` can only hold strings, jQuery's `data`store can hold arbitrary objects and is merely initialized from the `data-`attributes.

Comment: im aware but in OP´s context it doesnt make much sense as he/she doesnt have any object values

Answer (score 1):

The `<input>`'s `require` attribute [is of type `boolean`](http://w3c.github.io/html/sec-forms.html#the-required-attribute). It can't hold a numeric value:

> If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string
>   or a value that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the attribute’s
>   canonical name, with no leading or trailing white space.

What you wrote is actually [invalid HTML(5)](https://validator.w3.org/nu):

> Error: Bad value 5 for attribute required on element input.

However, your browser still handles this incorrect value gracefully by interpreting it as `"required"`.

See also: [Setting an attribute named "required" and any value, with JQuery, doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781355/setting-an-attribute-named-required-and-any-value-with-jquery-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 1):

Use the dataset of the element, for instance you can do:

```
<input type='text' runat='server' name='RM1' id='RM1' data-required='5' readonly>
```

When you need to retrieve the value of 'data-required' do:

```
$('#RM').data('required') // returns 5
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because [required](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-required-attribute) is a boolean attribute.

if you want to store custom data you can use `data-` attribute

**Example**

```js
var id = $('#RM1').data('id');

console.log(id);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' runat='server' name='RM1' id='RM1' data-id='5' readonly>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to HTML attribute reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes

The required attribute are reserved

Use attr like `requiredNum` instead, see example:

```js
console.log( $('#RM1').attr('requiredNum') )
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' runat='server' name='RM1' id='RM1' requiredNum='5' readonly>
```